# Como recuperar o histórico de scripts do PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Precisei reinstalar o PL/SQL Developer e assim perdi todo o histórico de scripts. É possível recuperar? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que você esteja falando do historico de comandos recentemente que foram executados no aplicativo PL/SQL, famoso <kbd>CTRL+E</kbd>. <s>Acho que não seja possível.</s>

Existe uma tabela no Oracle que você pode consultar o histórico de scripts executados, a `V$SQL`, você precisa acessar com um usuário com privilégios, como o `sys`.

```
SELECT * FROM v$sql
```

ou

```
select * from dba_hist_sqltext
```

<sup>Fonte: [ORACLE V$SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2B9340D7-4AA8-4894-94C0-D5990F67BE75.htm#REFRN30246)</sup>

Comment: executei esse scrip ai, mas apareceu um monte de coisas estranhas aqui, nada parecido com algum script que eu já tenha executado. Tb ja tinha checado essa fonte de onde vc mandou. Olhei no caminho AppData\Roaming\PLSQL Developer 12\ e o arquivo PLSRecall pelo jeito foi modificado. Acho que o programa não deveria substituir esse arquivo, caso vc precise dele como é o meu caso.

Comment: A consulta acima deveria resolver, tente colocar filtros por período na coluna `FIRST_LOAD_TIME`, ou parte da query que você fez, se lembrar de algum termo. Fiz uma edição adicionando outra tabela, veja se resolve.

Comment: Nada feito amigo.

Comment: A v$sql não só guarda SQLs !?